# Inserting many dynamically generated values into the same record with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have about ten form items that I want to insert into a MySQL db and each input in the form has a name that is also the table row name. You can get an idea of what I'm trying to do here:

```
foreach($_POST as $x=>$y) {

    if(!empty($y)) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO db.table (`$x`) values ('$y');";
            // execute
        }
}
```

...my problem is that I need  to make everything go into the same record. Right now each 'INSERT' is added to a  new record altogether. Would it be possible to get the id of the record of the very first 'INSERT' and then use 'Update' from there? Or is there a better way to  do it than this?

Thanks

Comment: PLEASE just stop and read about MySQL injection before you put this code into production. This is a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Yep, I'm working on getting the right output first and then I'm going to use prepared statements for everything

Comment: A better way would to do it **explicitly** and not trying to be smart with such loop stuff...it will only bite you in the end.

Comment: Oh good, just wanted to check :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should do something about the MySQL injection noted by @andy
Having said that you could try something like this, its simply adds all the values in one go.
There shouldn't really be a need to update at this point.

```
$columns = '';
$values = '';
$sql = "INSERT INTO db.table (%s) values (%s);";

foreach($_POST as $x=>$y) {
    if(!empty($y)) {
        $columns .= $x.',';
        $values .= $y.',';
    }
}

$columns = substr($columns,0,strlen($columns)-1));
$values = substr($values,0,strlen($values)-1));

$sql = sprintf($sql, $columns, $values);
//execute
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this function: [mysqli::insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)
You can execute the first query as an `insert`, get the generated id with that function, and then perform `update` queries.